# Web scraping: how to scrape data in the popup.html in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I am using Python to scrape data from a Chrome extension. Here is a sample page of the data I want,
[sample page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlV2O.png)

and there is html code if I inspect the small page of the Chrome extension.

I can use selenium to open the original nytimes webpage with Chrome extension enabled.

The problem is: how can I scrape data from this popup.html? What is the address for this html? I cannot even open this html in a new tab. Are there any ways to scrape this data? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Extensions can access current window but not vice-versa

Comment: Try opening the popup window as separate tab using its actual URL which you can see when you right-click the popup, click "Inspect", execute `location.href` in the console.